# Vue-js and Vuex: View not being updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am using Vuejs and Vuex to play around with. Currently i have an issue updating the view (vuejs) after an AJAX call has been fired. The view should update but it does not work if i use arrays, objects and booleans. If i update a string via the store commit this will get updated properly in the view. I do see in the vue develop tool the vuex / store getting updated properly. Once i make a change to the  part of example.vue hot reloading kicks in and the data is being shown.

I think i really mis a small thing but cannot figure out what is needed to trigger the update.

Currently i have set this up using the vue-cli tool and added Axios and Vuex via npm.

This is my code:
**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const StoreExample = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        customers: [],
        isLoading: false,
    },

    getters: {
        getCustomers: state => state.customers,
        isLoading: state => state.isLoading,
    },

    mutations: {
        setCustomers(state, payload) {
            state.customers.push(payload)
        },

        setLoading(state, payload) {
            state.isLoading = payload
        }
    },

    actions: {
        fetchCustomers({state, commit}) {
            commit('setLoading', true)
            axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/rkyih')
            .then(response => {
                commit('setCustomers', response.data)
                commit('setLoading', false)
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.error(e)
                commit('setLoading', false)
            })
        }
    },

    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { StoreExample } from './store/store.js'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: StoreExample,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**example.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{isLoading}}
        {{getCustomers}}
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'example',

        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchCustomers')
        },

        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getCustomers',
                'isLoading'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <example/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import example from './components/example'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    example
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you posting 4 code snippets, none of which is runnable?

Comment: Fixed the post to be properly being shown

Comment: If you're just "playing around" with Vue, I would skip VueEx for now.  Learn how Vue works first.  VueEx can be overkill for simple apps but can be quite valuable for large applications.

Comment: this example give you the problem? i don't think so..

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate your problem, however, I made use of your code and created a fully working example, which is basically 90% of your code.

In this example:

- I verified there's no difference between using getters or accessing the state directly.
- I also verified your problem has nothing to do with array.push(), as Vue's already wrapped around `Array.push()` to trigger updates.
- Instead of using axios, I used `fetch` for simplicity, which should work the same.

```js
const store  = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    customers: [],
    isLoading: false,
  },
  getters: {
    gCustomers: state => state.customers,
    gIsLoading: state => state.isLoading,
  },
  mutations: {
    setCustomers(state, payload) {
      state.customers = payload
    },
    setLoading(state, payload) {
       state.isLoading = payload
    },
    addCustomer(state, payload) {
      state.customers.push(payload)
    },
    resetCustomers(state) {
      state.customers = [];
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchCustomers({ state, commit }) {
      return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/rkyih')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
          commit('setCustomers', response)
          commit('setLoading', false)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e)
          commit('setLoading', false)
        });
    }
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dataId: '',
    isActive: '',
    age: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters([
      'gIsLoading', 'gCustomers' 
    ]),
    ...Vuex.mapState([
      'customers', 'isLoading'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions({
      getData: 'fetchCustomers'
    }),
    ...Vuex.mapMutations({
      resetData: 'resetCustomers'
    }),
    addCustomer() {
      this.$store.commit('addCustomer', {
        id: this.dataId,
        isActive: this.isActive,
        age: this.age,
        first_name: this.firstName,
        last_name: this.lastName,
      });
      this.resetInputs();
    },
    resetInputs() {
      this.dataId = ''
      this.isActive = ''
      this.age = ''
      this.firstName = ''
      this.lastName = ''
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="getData()">Get Data from API</button>
  <button v-on:click="resetData()">Reset Data</button>
  <div>
    <div>Id: <input v-model="dataId"/></div>
    <div>isActive: <input v-model="isActive" type="checkbox"/></div>
    <div>Age: <input v-model="age"/></div>
    <div>First Name: <input v-model="firstName"/></div>
    <div>Last Name: <input v-model="lastName"/></div>
    <div><button v-on:click="addCustomer()">Add Data</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <h3>mapState</h3>
      <div>Loading? {{isLoading}}</div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="customer in customers">
          {{customer}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <h3>magGetters</h3>
      <div>Loading? {{gIsLoading}}</div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="customer in gCustomers">
          {{customer}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LesleyTerpstra Please make use of this example to modify your code, if your problem still persists, let me know. We'll figure it out.